# Headless CMS: Wordpress Rest-API – Add links to existing posts/pages

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, content-management-system, headless, wordpress-rest-api

We want to use the Wordpress Rest-API to build a page decoupled from the backend. A few things still bother us though:
Within the wordpress backend one can add links in the content editor of a page or a post and one gets normally a list of all existing pages and posts of the same page to link to them. By decoupling the backend it does not know the exact urls to other pages and we need to provide this. Is there a possibility to tell wordpress what links are available?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for the answer:

There are two URL settings under Settings > General.

[image]

WordPress Address (URL) should be the URL for your api site. Like api.whatever.com.

Site Address (URL) should be the URL for the frontend. Like www.whatever.com.

This allows the internal linking to work properly in the Editor while keeping the backend site on a separate URL from a headless frontend.

Comment: Nice. That feature was for sure not existing, when I posted my question. Sweet that they go into that direction. 

Comment: I had to let the wp-json api URL be based on the wordpress address url instead of the site address. The following comment helped: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/1761#issuecomment-412876340

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. The WordPress REST API just provides a way to access posts, etc. from somewhere else part from the web site side (e.g. themes, etc). Pages would still be accessible from the admin backend *and* the JSON/REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/

Comment: We somehow solved it. I was not directly involved, but I think it was just a Wordpress setting that had to be changed.
Now internal linking and also the «View Site» link work properly.
Problem was: Backend was at api.whateverpage.com and the page itself (frontend) was at whateverotherurl.com. My question was how I could link from the api.whateverpage.com to the page where the actual frontend lies.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with WordPress you could ensure that you're not rewriting the permalinks.  That way they are all still site.com/?p=post-id

That way it's easy to parse fetch the new pages. Then replace the hrefs with whatever your frontend needs.

You could use the ID to fetch the slug of the new post immediately.

Or you could even keep a mapping in your presentation layer of IDs to your own slugs.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the site_url doesn't work for me.

Since I also have a wordpress theme with custom rest controllers
Plus the wp-json breaks if I change the site url

My backend is hosted at digital ocean app
My frontend is hosted at vercel

I fixed it by using a wordpress plugin called make-paths-relative
But since my backend doesnt know where my frontend is I added one change within the plugin at:

frontend/class-make-paths-relative.php line 123

I added a constant FRONTEND_URL which i define in the wp-config
$relative_link = FRONTEND_URL.$link;

This changes both the permalink within my backend of a post, page or cpt
And changes internal links as wel, links within the content editor

I made a request to the plugin author as well